# Character goes inside incline wall when moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I write character controller script, and implemented moving by changing rigidbody.position, and when my character try move forward close to the wall, he falls a little into incline wall and floor.[Character already in another collider ( i held right arrow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxBeM.png)

I try make a cast and check if player collider are collide if he moves, but i think that bad resolve my problems , because it create a problems if i want move item by character body and etc.

I think it be possible reslove with unity rigidbody setting or a bit of code

My movement code:

```
public void Move(Vector2 direction)
{
    Vector2 directionAlongSurface = _surfaceSlider.GetDirection(direction.normalized); // It get direction if player try walk on a slope (forward - Vector2.Dot(forward, _normal) * _normal;)
    Vector2 offset = directionAlongSurface * (_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //var colliders = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(_boxCollider.transform.position, _boxCollider.size, 90, offset, offset.magnitude,_layerMask);
    //if(colliders.Length == 0) // 
    _rigidbody.position += offset;
}
```

P.S Character collider a bit goes inside even in a flat wall

Comment: In 3D scene, we usually add RigidBody and Mesh Collider (other types of colliders also work) on the character, and we simultaneously add different types of colliders (depends on the shape of the target and the efficiency) on other scene objects like the ground or the wall. Then we just easily let Unity to handle collisions and other physical effects. I wish this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

a) In your movement code, you are moving the Rigidbody with  `_rigidbody.position += offset;`. This is an incorrect way of moving a physics object. try instead,

```
rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + offset);
```

b) You might also want to check your Rigidbody settings, the **Collision detection modes**, to be exact. if you were to use fast moving GameObjects, you'd want **Continuous** collision detection mode instead of discrete.